# On dynamic theme change, Theme.of(context) colors are not updating

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I have a conditional theme widget:

```
 return Theme(
        data: themeMode == ThemeMode.light ? formThemeTwo : formThemeTwoDark,
        child: Scaffold(
```

That changes the theme depending on the ThemeMode.

When the theme changes, this doesn't change:

```
TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: 40,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)
```

So there are two themes, and when the theme changes to formThemeTwoDark, `Theme.of(context).primaryColor` is not updating to use the primaryColor of formThemeTwoDark. It is updating colors that are not declared by using `Theme.of(context)` (e.g. widgets that don't specify the color at all and instead use the themes default).

Comment: Have you found the solution?